# Find active winform in solution explorer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I started working on a existing solution that has a very large number of Winforms. Is there a quick way to find the design time form, in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, when the application is running?

Please  note: debug/break will only help me find modal forms (dialogs). I am interested in finding modeless winforms too. I don't consider plowing through design time menus and events as a quick way..

Comment: What do you mean by `design time form`?

Comment: I think he means the form that is now active at runtime, how to find that form in the solution explorer in vs

Comment: A debugger can only show you what code is currently running.  Which, if you did it right, is *not* any code in the active window.  The normal state of a UI class is to patiently wait until something interesting happened.  Like a Click event.  So no, this is not possible.  The text displayed in the titlebar of the window is your best lead to find the matching Form class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also make an debug menu item on you main form and put in it :

```
string test = string.Empty;
foreach (Form item in Application.OpenForms)
{
    test += item.GetType().ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
} 
MessageBox.Show(test);
```

This will give you a list of openforms just like Markus G suggested but without the need of creating a form for this.

Also look at this :

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform(v=vs.110).aspx

It explains how you can identify the active form, but as usual microsoft has made things a bit complex by having 2 methods, one for mdi forms and one for none mdi forms

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want:

With Application.OpenForms ([click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx))

You'll get a list of all open Forms which belongs to you project.
Then you can easily find out the form in the Explorer.

Comment: How to use this when the application is running ? Which is what the OP asked.

Comment: Oh, then he could create a timer (or event) which updates every second in another form to see which forms are running.   I don't see the problem...  @OP Please answer

Comment: I'd rather not program at all to find out the active form, but it seems like that's not possible. I'll wait a bit to see if there are other solutions.